# result time of answer is very long, how to reduce it while using jpa?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "demo")
    public class DemoEntity {

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "demo_type_id", nullable = false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "demo_entity_record_type", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"demo_entity_id"))
    private Set<RecordType> recordTypes = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "demo_type_id", nullable = false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "demo_entity_record_type1", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"demo_entity_id"))
    private Set<DemoType> demoTypes1 = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "demo_type_id", nullable = false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "demo_entity_record_type2", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"demo_entity_id"))
    private Set<RecorType> recordTypes2 = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

I have 3000 records of entity in DB. When I try to get 3000 entities I see in logs:

```
3000 select to entity table
3000 select to test_entity_record_type table by test_entity_id
3000 select to test_entity_record_type1 table by test_entity_id
3000 select to test_entity_record_type2 table by test_entity_id
```

As result time of answer is very long. How to reduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @BatchSize annotation:

```
@BatchSize(size = 1000)
private Set<RecordType> recordTypes = new HashSet<>();
```

Let me know if this works.